# Endpoint configuration for Service Fabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I deployed an app on Service Fabric and there's an HTTP listener spawned inside. How can I configure the listening URL in relation to app/cluster? 
More precisely, is there any way to build this URL inside the app by retrieving some environment/role parameter ?

Suppose my cluster is called "test", then it will be available at: test.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com. If I have an app called "Sample" for which I configured an endpoint called "SampleTypeEndpoint" inside ServiceManifest.xml, what would be the complete URL my app would listen to?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about the DNS name of your cluster that external users will access?

Comment: as I see it, every application can define its endpoints, how are they resolved in relation to the name of the cluster? In my case, the cluster name is test.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com, is it possible to retrieve it in a programatic way inside the app? And also, how is the endpoint name used in relation to the cluster URL? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The endpoints you configure in ServiceManifest.xml right now fulfill two purposes:

1. Allow Service Fabric to provide a unique port from an application port range, if you don't need a well-known port.
2. When opening a web server that uses http.sys, allow Service Fabric to set up URL ACLs for a random port or a well-known port (80, 443, etc) and certificate ACLs for HTTPS.

That's basically it. The actual address on which you open a listener is up to you to determine. Typically, you open a listener on the node IP and use a NAT for ingress traffic on a domain name. In Azure, the NAT is the Azure Load Balancer which is automatically configured to accept traffic on your cluster's VIP as well as the .region.cloudapp.azure.com domain.

Here's a more thorough overview of how this works on Service Fabric cluster in Azure: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services/

Comment: thanks, it seems the Load Balancing rules have to be set for redirecting HTTP traffic. I was wondering if it's possible to deploy different applications to the cluster, each with a listener on HTTP 80, how would the requests be distributed in this case?

Comment: It's also possible to get that endpoint info using the SF APIs and this is what's done when using SF's programming models. (in example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-webapi). 
It would be useful if SF also passed that info to guest executables via environment variables like other platforms do.